# How can I retrieve all user's profiles?

Tags: user-profile

I need to check the department of each user in the collection. What do I need to use to do that?

Comment: what version of sharepoint?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to create a visual web part via visual studio and use Server-side object model via C# and use this code to get all user profile list based on property

```
using (SPSite site = new SPSite("http://portal/"))
{
        ServerContext context = ServerContext.GetContext(site);
        UserProfileManager profileManager = new UserProfileManager(context);

        foreach (UserProfile profile in profileManager)
       {
             Console.WriteLine(profile[PropertyConstants.Department]);
       }
}
```

For more details check [How to: Retrieve User Profile Properties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ms544366(v=office.14).aspx)

If you need to work with javascript object model Check also  [How to: Retrieve user profile properties by using the JavaScript object model in SharePoint 2013](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj920104.aspx)

If you need to use PowerShell

```
 #Add SharePoint PowerShell SnapIn if not already added 
    if ((Get-PSSnapin "Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue) -eq $null) { 
        Add-PSSnapin "Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell" 
    } 


    $site = new-object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite("http://WebapplicationURL/");  
    $ServiceContext = [Microsoft.SharePoint.SPServiceContext]::GetContext($site);  

    #Get UserProfileManager from the My Site Host Site context 
    $ProfileManager = new-object Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.UserProfileManager($ServiceContext)    
    $AllProfiles = $ProfileManager.GetEnumerator()  

    foreach($profile in $AllProfiles)  
    {  
        $DisplayName = $profile.DisplayName  
        $AccountName = $profile[[Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.PropertyConstants]::AccountName].Value  


        #Here goes writing Logic to your SharePoint List + Check if account already existing in the SharePoint list then ignore writing.......
        write-host "Profile for account ", $AccountName 


    }  

    $site.Dispose()
```

Ref : [How to return all user profiles](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/90838/how-to-return-all-user-profiles)